# Datepicker event noncalling

Tags: jquery-ui, events, datepicker

I have a mobile datepicker that works except for its event functions, which are not called. What is the problem?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#calendar").datepicker({
    onSelect: function () { alert('1'); },
    beforeShow: function () { alert('2'); },
    beforeShowDay: function () { alert('3'); }
});
</script>

<div>
<input id="calendar" type="date"/>  
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure looks fine, check if there's any JS error before. Do you use firebug or similar tools?

Comment: I use Chrome's tools. There is no error.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry before I haven't realised of the input type that's not correct. Datepicker usually works with **input type text**.

**Date** is a new input type on [HTML5](http://wufoo.com/html5/types/4-date.html), you are using that calendar instead of jQuery datepicker, that's why events doesn't work.

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jmva89/Lp2Jn/2/) for your example.

I would suggest you to use datepicker because *input=date* isn't supported by many browsers and has less options.

I expect that in near future we could use HTML 5 features supported by all browsers and write less javascript code.

Comment: I want to use the calendar, not the bar that is above it and produces a small calendar when clicked. Only date input allows this. What is the best approach to get events to work?

Comment: Also, does not produce alerts even if I use "text" instead of "date".

Comment: As I told you before, you must use input type text NOT date, the calendar you are using is HTML5 not jQuery. That's why events doesn't work. You could specify the start dates and end dates on your datepicker and in the input field.

Comment: I updated the fiddle example to display a non editable default date. http://jsfiddle.net/jmva89/Lp2Jn/6/ The example calendar there hasn't any CSS file. You could pick any design from here: http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/